# Finding a complement of a regular language

Tags: regular-language, computation-theory

Could you help me please to find a complement of a language, which ends with `abab - (a|b)*abab (over an alphabet {a,b})`

I guess, the complement must contain all string, that don't end with abab. 
One can try to do it with Rij-Algorithm after building a DFA for complement of `(a|b)*abab`, but pleaseee, help me to understand how it works without Automaton and Rij (because that Automaton has 5 states).

Ok, the words are not allowed to end with `abab`. There are 2<sup>4</sup> ways for four letters of `a`'s and `b`'s at the end. Okay, `abab` must be erased so there are 15 combinations. Does it mean, that the complement-language is `(a|b)*`.(union of all those combinations of `a`'s and `b`'s without `abab`)? But does `(a|b)` still stay the same at the beginning?

Help me please to understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I quiet don't understand you, but isn't it much simplier. I'e `(a|b)*(a|bb|aab|bbab)` or event `(a|b)*(a|(b|(a|bb)a)b)`?

P.S. Don't forget that there is words shorter than `abab` and all of them should be included too. I.e. `(a|b){0,3}` (where `{0,3}` denotes amount of repeats [0; 3])

Comment: Thank you for your response. 

I'm not sure, whether I understand how you think doing this.
So we don't need all other combinations of four letters (over {a,b})? And (a|b)* stays the same? Does it mean, that if we have some language with Kleene star it stays always as it was?

Comment: Yes. Since we have anchoring to the end of word its enough to make that last part of word incompatible. So starting from last letter I start to iterate and at each step I go in two sets: mismatch - means you can have anything else right after it; match - you should have mismatch at further steps. About last question I wouldn't be so sure. Consider complement language for `(a|b)*abab(a|b)*` - the only place where those `(a|b)*` will be allowed is for describing words with length shorter than 4. Other probably would contain single letter under star operator.